# perl open() injection prevention

Tags: perl, security, code-injection

I have read that the open() command with 2 arguments is vulnerable to injection whereas the open() command with 3 arguments isn't inject-able.

SAy I have a directory where all my files have a common prefix, i.e "file-" so an example filename would be, file-SomeSourceCode.txt

How would something like `open(FILEHANDLE, "some/random/dir/file-" . $fileextension)` be vulnerable?

where `$fileextension` could be any sort of 'filename' per say. As far as I understand, this would not be vulnerable to a filename like `| shutdown -r |` which would execute the command to the server.

Comment: It might not be vulnerable if the file name argument starts with a literal string (though I wouldn't bet large sums on it). The real vulnerability is when the argument is a variable name, perhaps derived without checking from a command-line argument. In any case, there's no good reason not to use the 3-argument version of `open`. Are you concerned about the safety of some old code that you're not able to update?

Comment: It's a question of danger vs. overhead. There is a danger. This danger is completely removed by 3 argument `open`. Why bother trying to mitigate this risk, when you don't need to take it in the first place.

Comment: A lot of the Secure Programming Techniques chapter in Mastering Perl shows these sorts of things.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
open(my $fh, "some/random/dir/file-" . $user_text)
```

is completely vulnerable. Not only does the improper injection make it impossible to open a file named

```
some/random/dir/file-foo|
```

it can be used to execute arbitrary commands

```
$ perl -e'open(my $fh, "file-".$ARGV[0])' ' ; echo 0wned >&2 |'
sh: 1: file-: not found
0wned
```

Comment: I think that's an excellent answer as to why 2 arg `open` should never be used - sure, you can ensure you validate your inputs, and be careful, but why bother when you can ensure the problem never existed in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I would comment on @ikegami excellent post but I don't have permission.

Another possible payload vector is to start the malicious input with = (equal), that way the name already hardcoded will be handle as a shell variable.

```
perl -e'open(my $fh, "file".$ARGV[0])' '=foo echo 0wned >&2 |'
```

In some cases cgi scripts stop on errors, with that payload an error isn't generated.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest possible vulnerability is when your `$fileextension` suddenly becomes `/../../../../../etc/passwd`. Another possibility is to make your `"some/random/dir/file-" . $fileextension` point to some existing executable file, in that case a trick with adding `| any-command |` will perfectly work.

Comment: Note: That would require a dir that starts with `some/random/dir/file-`

Comment: agree - your idea of passing the shell command directly is much better.

Comment: This has nothing to do with two-arg open; three-arg open would be equally vulnerable to this.